# Python urlopen does not work for every website

Tags: python, web, https, urllib, urlopen

Hi i have a working code, which opens (with urlopen from urllib.request) perfectly most of the websites I tell him to. 
But for some reason this doesn't seem to work for some specific websites. I don't even get an error, my code just runs forever without any progess. The websites I try to open are all https websites, including those which don't work. But I can open the website manually and it works perfectly fine, so it's not like the website is down or anything. Anyone any clue why that is?
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

```
url = r'https://www.mouser.de/'
url_text = uReq(url)
html_text = url_text.read()
```

Comment: Have you tried changing user agent string to something that simulates actual browser? IME, some sites filter non-brows user agents away.

Comment: Can you post the code, and add the different websites?

Comment: Sorry i added my code. it is this website i can't reach. How can I simulate and actual browser?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a `User-Agent` like used by a real browser.
This code, taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), is an example of how to use a `User-Agent`.

```py
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')
# Customize the default User-Agent header value:
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'urllib-example/0.1 (Contact: . . .)')
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```